# Augmented synthetic data vs trainning with not augmented synthetic data but augmentation on the batch?

Tags: keras

Augmented synthetic data vs trainning with not augmented synthetic data but augmentation on the batch?
As the title says, which is better?

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding your question. Can you please provide some few more information, what you want to achieve or discuss?

Comment: data with processing before or during training, which is better period?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by augmented synthetic data and augmentation on the batch? It would be nice if you provided some context, like what kind of problem you are trying to solve with keras and what dataset we are talking about.

Generally, if you are (I'm assuming) trying to train deep neural networks, data augmentation is used to artificially increase your training set size. This can also be applied to synthetic data. Usually this is done when loading a batch of data, randomly applying "distortions" that should make your net more robust.

Comment: but which is better? or the same?

Comment: If you're doing data augmentation when you load your batch, so during training, you can apply different changes to the image every time you feed it to the network. That's why I would recommend that approach.